# How to create downwards elliptical circle path in unity3d?

Tags: graphics, 3d, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity3d I want to make a path for animated object.
The path must be # elliptical circle # or # spring shape path #
I think there is a way to draw this path based on mathematics equation is it true?
or should I draw it using 3dmax.
Any help or related tutorial for this problem?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [helpful link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/228138/draw-path-to-follow.html) for drawing a path w/ the mouse in game.

If you want to draw a spring programmatically you can use a Catmullrom or Bezier spline:

```
double bezier(double t, double p0,double p1,double p2,double p3){
    double t2 = t*t;
    double t3 = t2 * t;
    return (0.16667 *(  t3  *   (-p0 +  3 * p1 + -3 * p2 + p3) +    \
                    t2  *   (3 * p0 + -6 * p1 + 3 * p2) +       \
                    t   *   (-3*p0 + 3*p2) +                    \
                    1   *   (p0 + 4*p1 + p2)));
}
double catmullrom(double t, double p0,double p1,double p2,double p3){
    double t2 = t*t;
    double t3 = t2 * t;
    return (0.5 *(      (2 * p1) + (-p0 + p2) * t +(2*p0 - 5*p1 + 4*p2 - p3) * t2 +(-p0 + 3*p1- 3*p2 + p3) * t3));
}
```

The inputs p0,p1,p2,p3 are the 4 control points for a particular segment.  To see a spiral building example, the rest of [this code can be found on my Github page](https://github.com/Jerdak/SplineDemo/blob/master/Splines/Splines.cpp).  Look at **BuildPath()** in particular to see how to use those functions to build a continuous path.  I dislike linking to external accounts but my usage example is a little too big for an SO answer.

If you want to draw an ellipse, the simplest way I can think is to solve the basic equation and build a ring of points:

```
List<Vector3> pts = new List<Vector3>();
for(float x=-2.0f; x<2.0f;x+=0.1){
    y = sqrt( (1-x^2/a^2) * b^2 );//from eq. x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2=1; 
    pts.Add(new Vector3(x,y,0));
}
```

That code assumes you have a [horizontal major axis](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/ellipse/equation-of-ellipse.php) where 'a' is the radius of the horizontal major axis, 'b' is the radius of the vertical minor axis.  Build the ellipse first along the X/Y axes and then apply whatever transform you wish to orient the ellipse.

Alternatively, and I don't have code for this, you can use the [general parametric equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#General_parametric_form) to generate a rotated ellipse already off origin.

Comment: do you have build path in C#

Comment: @Mohammed Sadly no, but nothing I do is particularly fancy, it should be trivial to convert.